# How to update Android LiveData Factory

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata, android-pagedlistview

I am using [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) database layer with [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) and [PagedList](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/paging/PagedList) to render a `ReceycleView` List of chat messages in my app.

This is how my setup looks like:

```
    DataSource.Factory<Integer, Message> factory = ChatDb.getMessages(conversation);
    PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
            .setPageSize(50)
            .build();
    LiveData<PagedList<Message>> liveData = new LivePagedListBuilder<>(factory, config)
            .build();
    liveData.observe(this, adapter::submitList);
```

When the user moves to a new conversation, I need to re-query Room with a new `conversation` object.

What would be the proper way to clean up the old `factory` and the `liveData`, and is there a way to reuse any of those?